# Why do action creators have a type property?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm making a function that accepts an array of [`Action`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/types/actions.ts#L18-L20)s, a type that only requires it to have a `type` property. While writing tests for that function I made a mistake and passed the Action Creator directly instead of the result of calling it, making the test to fail. After I found the error, I realized typescript didn't complain, because [`BaseActionCreator`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.7.1/packages/toolkit/src/createAction.ts#L84-L87) also has a `type` property so for typescript they are interchangeable if I pass any of them as an argument (which it seems I don't want to happen).

Is there any particular reason for this? and, is there a way to prevent Action Creators from being accepted as arguments?

An example of what's going can be seen at: https://codesandbox.io/embed/typescript-playground-export-forked-0qjt4k?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import { Action, createAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

function myFunction(actions: Action[]) {
  actions.forEach((action) => console.log(action.type));
}

const customActionCreator = createAction("CUSTOM");

myFunction([customActionCreator()]);
myFunction([customActionCreator]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `BaseActionCreator` (or in your case, a `ActionCreatorWithoutPayload`) requires the `type` property to compare itself with other action creators.

We can see it being used inside the `.match` method.

```
actionCreator.match = (action: Action<unknown>): action is PayloadAction =>
    action.type === type
```

---

This means that any `ActionCreatorWithoutPayload` is also assignable to `Action` since they both have the `payload` and `type` properties. But we essentially want to disallow `ActionCreatorWithoutPayload` from being passed to the function.

We could look at what properties `ActionCreatorWithoutPayload` has addtionally. Since it is a function, it has the `call` property which we can *"blacklist"* by intersecting `Action` with  `{ call?: never }`.

```
function myFunction(actions: (Action & { call?: never })[]) {
  actions.forEach((action) => console.log(action.type));
}
```

Which gives us the desired error.

```
myFunction([customActionCreator()]);

myFunction([customActionCreator]);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Type 'ActionCreatorWithoutPayload<"CUSTOM">' is 
//                              not assignable to type '{ call?: undefined; }
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQMY2BAdgGjqqAUwEMZC0Ns4BfOAMyghDgCIABIgEwFcAPAKwDOAehgQIAGwDWwGCwDcAKEV1uWdJixwQATwBiajdgAUxI1kEAuOMYqa4AMkT5iEiQH5rWQgDdCUGgBKAG0AXUDERTg4M0oLADo6aABRMwALY1NzCIBeAD58bEFJQniJCABzLLj4mB0wQkDApWplVCL4VG5BMRA7bABhIlJoOBz8YbJ+rGMWAYBVAGUAFQB5AFkWZuVdA3U442CunqZpoZIxKGNA8KVFXcMDo+7es8noW8VhYWjfv7gAHpA4Eg0EguDLeqEOAAcjeF2gAHVZGkINwYAAFYg6crETgAHjmSzWmzyMLgwEEcC+P3+dPpDN+WAg8GIgkEwAqWGIACMJNCxHA6g1YUhUK4PNY1JxCHRgN5OPIaEA)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was hoping would relay on some utility type for typescript but your solution worked as a charm!